# launchd doesn't get triggered

Tags: ios, macos, ipad, plist, launchd

I've written this `mailCopy.`plist file, that is supposed to just echo "GotTriggered" into a log file, when a mail arrives.

```
<?xml version=1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>Mail</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>echo</string>
<string>GotTriggered</string>
</array>
<key>WatchFiles</key>
<array>
    <string>/var/mobile/Library/Mail/Protected\ Index-wal</string>
</array>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/var/log/mailCopy.log</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/var/log/mailCopy_err.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The file `Protected Index-wal` *is* (verified) changed whenever the iPad (iOS 9.02, jailbroken) receives an incoming e-mail, but no log, neither error nor regular is written, when an e-mail is received.

I've loaded the file using `launchd load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/mailCopy.plist`. It is loaded, because if I try the same command again, it informs me, that the plist file is already loaded.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need a `Program` key which is the full path to the echo program. (Which should match the first item in `ProgramArguments`.)

Comment: I just changed it to /bin/echo (where it is located), but that doesn't change anything unfortunately.